# Excel Need to Populate one column with the value of another based on the original value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Column "I" has the values already, I want column "J" to populate with the information on the KEY   I tried the formula IF(I153=2.12,W185) and that gives me one result but I need it to choose the right KEY value depending on what Designation Value is. Can you please Help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1) function.

Basically, you put the formula in column J.  The formula takes the value in column I, the table containing the key and desired result (columns V & W), and the column number in the table that you want returned (2).

Comment: This is really more the kind of helpful hint that would go in a comment than a solution.